# ASP.NET MVC 2 route errors - problems when using cottsak's solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, ninject, http-status-code-404

I figured it'd be easier to ask here, where I can post some code, than in the comments of his solution.  To see his solution, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095).

EDIT: Some progress, but a new error.  In my ErrorController class, I'm getting a NotImplementedException:

```
public ActionResult InvokeHttp404(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    IKernel kernal = new StandardKernel();
    IController errorController = kernal.Get<ErrorController>();
    var errorRoute = new RouteData();
    errorRoute.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
    errorRoute.Values.Add("action", "Http404");
    errorRoute.Values.Add("path", httpContext.Request.Url.OriginalString);
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
         httpContext, errorRoute)); // <-- here

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Specifically, the exception message is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'HandiGamer.WebUI.Controllers.NotFoundViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

I'm not sure which dictionary it's referring to, and MSDN has been less than helpful.

Comment: Seems like your `errorController` instance is not working as expected for some reason. I'm not a Ninject guru so perhaps i can't help much here.

Comment: That's okay... at least I have an idea of where to look.

Comment: StructureMap is really easy to get going. Maybe try swapping it in and getting everything working then slowly swapping back Ninject - this trial/error process may slowly identify the ugly head(source) of the problem.

Comment: I may do that, if I can't figure it out.  Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: I would recommend you the [following solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/620559#620559).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh God, the problem was me being an idiot.  I neglected to change my view, so it was still anticipating a simple `string` for its view model rather than a `NotFoundViewModel`.  Since `IController.Execute()` was being called in the raw, it was throwing an exception due to the view's internal dictionary not being set to accept the view model.

@cottsak, thanks for all your help and patience.